# How do I setup Swashbucle to find the swagger.json when some of the request path is replaced?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'am trying to upgrade a .net api to .net core 3.1.
For this to work I also have to upgrade to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.
This works out of the box in localhost, but when deployed it can't find the swagger.json file.

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{    
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Request.Path = context.Request.Path.Value.Replace("/api-svc", "");
        await next.Invoke();
    });
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
    {
        s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "api v1");
    });
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseMiddleware<CustomExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

> Fetch error: undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json

The network shows that it's trying to retrieve the file from this url:
https://api.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json
Which correctly gives the error:

> Load balancer has no matching route. There is something wrong with your request!.

The url should have been:
https://api.com/api-svc/swagger/v1/swagger.json. Because when I manually type this in it responds with the json file.

So I tried to set basepath (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1173);

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
    {
        s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "api v1");
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, request) =>
        {
            swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host.Value}{Configuration["VIRTUAL_PATH"]}" } };
        });
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
    {
        s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "api");
    });
}
```

But the same error persist. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[Update]

(https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1253)
Using relative paths made everything look correct:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(s => {
    s.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "api v1");
});
```

The problem now is that the actual api request url is https://api.com/health when it should be https://api.com/api-svc/health

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of testing I found the answer:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
    {
        s.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "api v1");
    });
}
else
{
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, request) =>
        {
            var path = Configuration["VIRTUAL_PATH"];
            swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> 
            {
                new OpenApiServer { Url = $"https://{request.Host.Value}{path}" } 
            };
        });
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
    {
        s.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "api");
    });
}
```

Comment: this worked for me too